# Is scanf("%4s%4s", b, b); well-defined?

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char b[5];
    scanf("%4s%4s", b, b);
    //My input: "qwer<Enter>sgsh<Enter>"
    printf("%s", b);
    //Output: sgsh
}
```

C99:
Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its stored value
modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression.

In this case, I am modifying the value of `b` `twice`. Isn't it `undefined behavior`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [this `scanf` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf):

> There is a sequence point after the action of each conversion specifier; this permits storing multiple fields in the same "sink" variable.

So what you're doing is defined and should work well.